# prove(disprove) asymptotic exact bound (theta)

Tags: asymptotics

I want to prove (or disprove) that

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\log_2 i = \Theta(n\log_2 n)\,,$$

but I totally get stuck with this example. May someone help me with that.

Comment: Use the fact that $\log a + \log b = \log (ab)$.

Comment: You can use LaTeX directly here (just put in dollars as you usually would), so I replaced your image with text.

Answer (score 2):

Asymptotically,

$$\frac{1}{4}n\log_2n < \frac{1}{2}n(\log_2n-1) = \sum_{i=\frac{n}{2}}^{n}\log_2\frac{n}{2}<\sum_{i=1}^{n} \log_2i < \sum_{i=1}^{n} \log_2 n = n \log_2 n\,.$$

Answer (score 1):

The LHS is $\log(n!)$, which is known, by Stirling's formula, to be asymptotic to $$\frac12\log(2\pi n)+n(\log(n) - 1).$$

You can conclude.